# After inserting/deleting datagridview not shows the inserted item

Tags: c#, winforms

```
private void btndelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (txtserch.Text == "")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Enter Customer name to delete");
    }
    else
    {
        l1.conn();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("delete from CUSTOMER where NAME='" + txtserch.Text + "'", l1.connection);
        int a = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        if (a == 1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Deleted Sucessfully");
            dataGridView1.Refresh();
            dataGridView1.RefreshEdit();
            dataGridView1.Update();
            txtserch.Text = "";
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Customer Not Exist");
            txtserch.Text = "";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: dear you have to rebind the grid

Answer (score 1):

`DataGridView.Refresh()` is graphics refresh, not data refresh.
Rebind your DatagridView to the source.

```
DataGridView dataGridView1 = new DataGridView();
dataGridView1.DataSource = source;

// Update Data in src1

dataGridView1.DataSource = null;
dataGridView1.DataSource = source;
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to refresh your grid rebind it..

```
MyGridView.DataSource = ds;
MyGridView.DataBind();
```

here *ds* is the datasource which you are providing to grid.

Refer this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fkx0cy6d.aspx) for details

Answer (score 0):

If you want to Bind Data to Gridview  after edit/delete/update actions,then you want to write below code of line

```
GridviewName.DataSource = ds;// retrieve the details and store in ds
GridViewName.DataBind();
```